# StringPath() function for C#

Tags: c#

I'm following this tutorial.  It asks me to paste this code into my Startup.cs file configure method:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
        LoginPath = new StringPath("/Account/Login"),
        AccessDeniedPath = new StringPath("/Home/Forbidden"),
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true
    });
```

the StringPath() object throws an error.  Missing directive or reference.  For whatever reason I get no results when I google StringPath() C# or anything close to that.  It doesn't suggest a namespace to include in my file.  What namespace does this object belong to?

Comment: `I'm following this tutorial` which?

Comment: http://www.arifyayalar.me/2016/11/01/asp-net-core-cookie-authentication-policy-based-authorization/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) or some copy of it, maybe with typos.

Take a look, here is usage of `PathString` structure and not `StringPath`.

Comment: On a side note do you know of any resources that would better show someone how to use CookieAuth?  The Microsoft documents seem like an excerpt of some project containing files/controllers/views I don't have.

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw No, i do not know any resources with complete examples:( I prefer to read MS specs and tutorials. Btw if this answer helps you, mark this as answer please:)